# ArrayList of byte[] to byte[] using stream in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an ArrayList of byte[] and I'm wondering if it's possible to convert this to a byte[] using stream from Java 8. All the arrays inside the ArrayList have the same size.

```
ArrayList<byte[]> buffer = new ArrayList();

byte[] output = buffer.stream(...)
```

Comment: Concat all the byte[] ?

Comment: Yes. I want all the bytes in the ArrayList in a unique byte array.

Comment: Related: [In Java 8, is there a ByteStream class?](//stackoverflow.com/q/32459683)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<byte[]> list = Arrays.asList("abc".getBytes(), "def".getBytes());
byte[] result = list.stream()
    .collect(
        () -> new ByteArrayOutputStream(),
        (b, e) -> b.write(e, 0, e.length),
        (a, b) -> {}).toByteArray();
System.out.println(new String(result));
// -> abcdef
```

Comment: Is this only for API level 24 and above?

Comment: @UmairM I don't know "API level 24".  But it requires Java 8 or above.

Comment: Why is the combiner a no-op? `b.writeTo(a);` suffices.

Comment: When you use `b.write(e, 0, e.length)`, you don’t need to deal with `IOException`, so the entire lambda expression simplifies to `(b, e) -> b.write(e, 0, e.length)`. Further, I can only second @user167019, don’t write broken combiner functions. Especially when there is a simple straight-forward implementation like `b.writeTo(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible solution with the Guava library:

```java
List<byte[]> list = Arrays.asList("abc".getBytes(), "def".getBytes());
byte[] res = Bytes.toArray(list.stream()
        .map(byteArray -> Bytes.asList(byteArray))
        .flatMap(listArray -> listArray.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

`flatMap` should be what you are looking for, ideally it should look like this:

```
byte[] output = buffer.stream().flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x)).toArray(n -> new byte[n])
```

But it does not compile.

With some helper methods:

```
private Byte[] box(final byte[] arr) {
    final Byte[] res = new Byte[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}
private byte[] unBox(final Byte[] arr) {
    final byte[] res = new byte[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

The following should work (but not very nice or efficient):

```
byte[] output = unBox(buffer.stream().flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(box(x))).toArray(n -> new Byte[n]));
```

Comment: Does not compile.

Comment: `toArray` can't be used to output a primitive array (generics don't allow it). This still won't compile.

Comment: Updated with a compiling version. (Though I admit it is not very nice.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Guava library](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#asList(byte...)), it has `Bytes` which supports converting `byte[]` to `List<Byte>` and back via:

```
public static List<Byte> asList(byte... backingArray)
```

and

```
public static byte[] toArray(Collection<? extends Number> collection)
```

Another option is to simply iterate and copy the arrays, one by one, to one big byte[], it seems to me simpler and more straightforward that the code in the accepted answer...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<byte[]> list = Arrays.asList("abc".getBytes(), "def".getBytes());
    byte[] flattened= flatByteList(list);
    System.out.println(new String(flattened)); // abcdef
}

private static byte[] flatByteList(List<byte[]> list) {
    int byteArrlength = list.get(0).length;
    byte[] result = new byte[list.size() * byteArrlength]; // since all the arrays have the same size
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        byte[] arr = list.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < byteArrlength; j++) {
            result[i * byteArrlength + j] = arr[j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```