# How to convert an array of objects to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, stream, byte, primitive

i have an array of Objects. Those objects offer the method `toByteArray()`.
If i call `foo.toByteArray()` I will get the byte-representation of this object.

I am struggling to convert this array of objects into a byte array.

My first approach was:

```java
Arrays.stream(fooArray).map((fooEntry) -> fooEntry.toByteArray()).toArray();
```

However, this does return an array of objects instead of byte[].
What's the easiest way to do what I want?

Comment: Conceptually you need to use `flatMap` instead of `map`. However, it’s not quite as simple as that with arrays.

Comment: What is your implementation of `toByteArray()` for the objects?

Comment: Basically the object represents a byte value and a short value. And toByteArray does the following:
`return new byte[] {validFlag, (byte) ((value>> Byte.SIZE) & BinaryDataUtil.BYTE_MASK), (byte) (value & BinaryDataUtil.BYTE_MASK) };`

Answer (score 0):

An array is serializable, so as long as your Objects are also serializable then you should be able to convert the Array to a byte[] without having to access the toByteArray() method of the elements.

First make sure your Object is Serializable:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
//... Your class 
}
```

Now you should be able to serialise the whole Array using `ByteArrayOutputStream:`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(fooArray);
oos.flush();
byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach as I'm quiet new to Java, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer to the following SO question...
[ArrayList of byte[] to byte[] using stream in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394290/arraylist-of-byte-to-byte-using-stream-in-java)
and making a simple implementation of method `toByteArray`, hopefully the following provides what you require. (Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {
    public byte[] toByteArray() {
        return new byte[]{(byte) -1};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo[] fooArray = new Foo[]{new Foo(), new Foo()};
        byte[] bytes = Arrays.stream(fooArray)
                             .map(foo -> foo.toByteArray())
                             .collect(() -> new ByteArrayOutputStream(),
                                      (b, e) -> b.write(e, 0, e.length),
                                      (a, b) -> {
                                          try {
                                              b.writeTo(a);
                                          }
                                          catch (IOException x) {
                                              throw new UncheckedIOException(x);
                                          }
                                      })
                             .toByteArray();
    }
}
```

`map` returns a stream where every element in the stream is a byte array, i.e. `byte[]`. Then you simply collect all the bytes from all the byte arrays into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then you call method `toByteArray` of class `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Note that method `writeTo` throws `IOException` and checked exceptions are not simple to handle in lambda expressions. Hence it is wrapped in `UncheckedIOException` which is an unchecked exception.